# how to add a gap between clips in adobe premiere pro?

Tags: premiere

I have a long video made of assembled cut clips and sometimes I have to insert a black gap between two clips, for instance

[image]

Commonly I would select all the afterwards clips and zooooom out and drag and drop them a bit after as to make this gap but I would like to know if there exists a shortcut or a command to do that without to zoom out and select and drag&drop because on a video with a lot of clips sometimes it is time taking..

Anything like tell adobe Premiere Pro, at this location where the cursor holds add a gap of n seconds ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing in Premiere is the nudge keyboard shortcut. Select the clips you want to move and hit <kbd>⌘ / ctrl</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>⌘ / ctrl</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> to nudge the clips one frame forward or back, and hold the shift key  ( <kbd>⌘ / ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>⌘ / ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> ) to make it 5 frames.

You can increase or decrease the amount it nudges in the preferences, so if you want <kbd>⌘ / ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> to nudge 5 seconds, open preferences then look for **trim** and change the **Large Trim Offset** amount to 125 (for 25fps, or 150 for 30fps).

Answer (score 1):

There is a much better way to do this.  If you have a Black Video clip (aka slug) in your Project, you can insert it (sliding all clips to the right) as follows:

Select and copy the Black Video clip.  Then at the point where you want to insert it, choose Edit > Paste Insert.

The clip or clips are pasted into the sequence, and the playhead jumps to the end of the pasted clip or clips.

If the Black Video clip you are inserting is longer or shorter in duration than what you exactly want, you can make a ripple edit to the slug and clips to the right will ripple accordingly.  See [this section](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/trimming-clips1.html) of the Premiere documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good trick for this:

just place whatever picture you want above the main video bar(into the 2nd track line) and then start to drag that image into the video while holding down the Ctrl key. this will move the whole video sequence to the right and then you can delete the image that you just used to create this new gap.

you can also pull the image to be a bit longer first to get a bigger gap

Comment: Allthough this is a way to do it, it is way to overkill. You can simply select all clips behind this point with the tool accesible thorugh "A" and move them as far as you want to create a gap

Comment: @TimothyLukasH. what does "accessible through "A" mean?

Comment: @barlop Press the "A" key on your keyboard

Comment: you only work on 1 minute videos or how the heck is selecting ALL of the clips not the actual overkill?

Comment: This actually makes sense: as opposed to using the "A" = "Track select forward" - Tool, inserting an image / a clip in the described way will make the sequence markers move together with your clips